# Elasticbeanstalk failed to fetch AWS' Relational Database Service(RDS)

Tags: error-handling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am using Django and react for my app. For database I used `postgresql`. I have created AWS' `RDS` and connect my database with PostgreSQL's `psADMID`. My app works fine in localhost. I can see the data in my frontend. I deployed my code in `Elasticbeanstalk` but the problem is, in my frontend it `failed to fetch the data,` you can see in console with [link](http://todo-deploy.eba-9nb6wjcm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/). I also tried to create `snapshots` and connect with `Elasticbeanstalk's environment` but it still shows me the error. I don't know how to fix it.

**This is project settings**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'mzhlo8oesrwf_we%aj$4$n)@***'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['todo-deploy.eba-9nb6wjcm.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'api',

    'rest_framework',

    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'article',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '*********',
        'HOST': 'database-2.*****spj1h.u*****1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static')
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```